# Visual Studio 2017 Cordova App The project system has encountered an error

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-cordova

I have a HTML5/JavaScript Cordova application and when I start it this message error comes up (sometimes just one time, sometimes twice).

[image: Error]

Here's the text in the `.txt` file:

> 6/25/2018 3:13:54 PM
>   Recoverable
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.Common.MSBuildEventHandler.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.VsOutputWindowLogger.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
>
> 6/25/2018 3:13:54 PM
>   Recoverable
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.Common.MSBuildEventHandler.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.VsOutputWindowLogger.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
>
> 6/25/2018 3:13:54 PM
>   Recoverable
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.Common.MSBuildEventHandler.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.VsOutputWindowLogger.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
>
> 6/25/2018 3:13:54 PM
>   Recoverable
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.VSPackages.Common.MSBuildEventHandler.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Implementation.Build.VsOutputWindowLogger.d__19.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional Edition 15.7.4

After clicking OK once or twice, everything goes back to normal, **how can I get rid of this message?**

Comment: Try reinstalling Visual Studio because there are not many other options in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first check all the references for Android Home, Java Home and npm. then try changing your **.jsproj** file in Notepad like

this

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>false</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled></PropertyGroup>
```

to

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>True</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
<TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>false</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled</PropertyGroup>
```

if it didn't do it then try repair your vs installation.

Comment: Repairing Visual Studio was the solution!